# Does this Chrome extension of reporting who visits your Facebook profile work?

Tags: facebook

I found this Google extension in Google Web Store `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/profile-visitors-for-face/ihjbpjahiibmjdlcgodcnmpelpmilamk?hl=en`

It promises that one can see who visits his profile in Facebook. Does it work? Or will the others see that I use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a browser extension.

Comment: I think this is okay here because it's specifically interacting with the Web interface of Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't expose the data about who visits your profile or not. I had a look at the code of this extension—it seems like every time *you* visit someone else's profile, the extension records this to a shady URL (`http://profilevisitors.56kupdate.com/addons/profilevisitors/interface.php` to be specific), the Facebook ID of the person whom you visited.

And if the other user installs this extension, it will fetch the data from that site (this URL to be specific: `http://profilevisitors.56kupdate.com/addons/profilevisitors/list.xml`) and then report to that person that you had visited.

So this requires both the person to install the extension *and* leak personal info—for now just the Facebook ID, but considering it has access to all sites, don't be surprised if future updates start to steal information.

In short, it sorta does work, but requires both to install and leaks a whole lot of infomation. Don't install this.

Also, why in the world would you want to know who visited you?